# update svg xlink in react

Tags: reactjs, svg

I'm trying to update the `xlink:href` attribute in my svg file but it's not updating with the link I am passing to it so that it will display the jpg file as a background to the svg

How can I update the xlink attribute with my link?

**component.js**

```
if(this.state.image) {
  const backgrounds = svg.find('#bg')
  $(backgrounds).attr('xlink:href', https://local.devel:5601/media/material/uni-348-01_material.jpg);
}
```

**svg**

```
<defs>
    <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100%" height="100%">
        <image id="bg" xlink:href="" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
    </pattern>
</defs>
```

Comment: This looks like jQuery, you should use setAttributeNS not jQuery's attr so that the namespace is set correctly.

Comment: It throws an error if I try to use that `Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _jquery2.default)(...).setAttributeNS is not a function`

Comment: because setAttributeNS is a DOM method, not a jQuery method. Either get the DOM node directly or convert the jQuery object to the underlying DOM node.

Comment: could you please provide an example?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/get/

Comment: Surround the link adress with quotes.